# Predicting non linear asymptotes of a real valued function.

Tags: calculus, special-functions, graphing-functions

So i have a function

$y=\frac{x^3+2x+9}{\sqrt{4x^2+3x+2}}$.

At wolfram alpha they say that it has a *non linear* asymptote 
$y=\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{3x}{16}+ \frac{251}{256}$.

How do you predict this?

Comment: is it $$\frac{x^3+2x+9}{\sqrt{4x^2+3x+2}}$$?

Comment: Sorry , i added braces to make it more readable . Guess its not serving its purpose.

Comment: Question has been edited

Comment: $ y= \frac{x^3+2x+9}{2x} (1+\frac{3}{4x}+\frac{1}{2x^2})^{\frac{-1}{2}} $ ... binomially expand the second bracket ...

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit can u please elaborate ?

Comment: I'm confused because wolfram alpha says to me, the asymptote is $$y=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{13x}{16}-\frac{101}{256}$$

Comment: @Fakemistake well thats why i used proper brackets to that mathamaticia is able to understand it properly.

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote at all... I simply wrote "asymptote of (x^3+2x^2+9)/(sqrt(4x^2+3x+2))"

Comment: @Fakemistake well just write " y={x^3+2x+9}/{root(4x^2+3x+2)} asymptotes " :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ y= \frac{x^3+2x+9}{2x} (1+\frac{3}{4x}+\frac{1}{2x^2})^{\frac{-1}{2}} $ ... binomially expand the bracket ... 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(1+\frac{3}{4x}+\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)^{\frac{-1}{2}} &=&1+ \frac{-1}{2} \left(\frac{3}{4x}+\frac{1}{2x^2}\right) +\frac{\frac{-1}{2}(\frac{-1}{2}-1)}{2} \left(\frac{3}{4x}+\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)^2 +\cdots \\
&=&1+\frac{-3}{8x}+\frac{-5}{128x^2}+\cdots
\end{eqnarray*}
Now multiply this by $\frac{x^3+2x+9}{2x}$ ... we get $y=\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{3x}{16}+ \frac{251}{256} +o(\frac{1}{x})$.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I really appreciated your help.